# How can I connect to a remote IIS database on the same network?

Tags: database, iis

I'm creating a test server to add functionality for a webpage. The original server hosts a webpage that is connected to a database. In order to test on our test server, I need to connect to the database on the original server. How can I do this using the connection strings?

I'm sorry if this doesn't make sense. I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few common connection string formats that you could use.  Additional formats and database providers can be found on [www.connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/)

SQL Server Standard Security

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;
```

**myServerAddress**
The name of the original server.

**myDataBase**
The name of the database that you are attempting to connect to on that server.  If you go to the original server and look at how it connects to the database, it should provide this information.

**myUsername** and **myPassword** are self explanatory and these should also be found on the original server.  This is assuming the original server was using a SQL account.  If it was not, then use the below line of code.

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```